# Calculate days between dates without "extra" dates in leap years

Tags: java, date, jodatime

So, I have to calculate the amount of days between two dates buuuut not taking into account the extra days of leap years...

So, for example between 1st Jan. 2012 and 1st Jan. 2013 should result 365 instead of 366.

I came across a solution with [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

```
int days = Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(start), new DateTime(end)).getDays();
```

But I am not allowed to use that library... only Java API.

With Calendar I had no much luck:

```
Calendar startCal=new GregorianCalendar();
Calendar endCal=new GregorianCalendar();
startCal.setTime(start);
endCal.setTime(end);
endCal.add(Calendar.YEAR,-startCal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
endCal.add(Calendar.MONTH,-startCal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
endCal.add(Calendar.DATE,-startCal.get(Calendar.DATE));

int daysDifference=endCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
```

Any ideas which don't involve a lot of code?

Comment: Why would you want to calculate a value that you know to be wrong?

Comment: `Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(start), new DateTime(end)).getDays();` returns `366` and this is good result :)

Comment: Count the occurences of february 29th in your timeframe and substract it.

Comment: Because I have to :) Too long to explain, but is a part of the application I'm working in...

Comment: @diminuta Explaining why often results in a better solution using a different approach than the one you have considered. Personally, what you want to do just seems wrong.

Comment: It is not what I want to do, it is what I am asked to do... the thing is that I have to calculate days between the day an operation took place and when a formular has to be opened for a doctor to register data for a patient. If the days between an operation an a formular are, let's say 1 month... and the operation took place a 21th februar...

Comment: they want the formular to open 21th march, despite that's less than a whole month. They store the difference in days between the operation day and the day the formular should open to display it, but they don't store that date but the real date when the formular is opened... don't ask me why, and I can't change that... so what I should do is what they pay me for... and it is to calculate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong with with this statement:

> So, for example between 1st Jan. 2012 and 1st Jan. 2013 should result 365 instead of 366.

JodaTime returns **366** in this situation, tested.

### Solution without JodaTime

```
GregorianCalendar start = new GregorianCalendar(2012, 0, 1);
GregorianCalendar end = new GregorianCalendar(2013, 0, 1);
int days = (end.get(Calendar.YEAR) - start.get(Calendar.YEAR)) * 365 +
        (end.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) - start.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
System.out.println(days);
```

returns `365`.

Comment: Well I was certainly wrong with the joda time, but I don't know how I tested it and it worked for some dates that contained leap years and not... Although you answered a little bit later than http://stackoverflow.com/users/3049628/tim-b I think your answer is more elaborated.

Comment: Yes, it's the same answer but this one gives you the actual code. Accepting this one is fair :D

Comment: @MariuszS Your first line confuses me: `You are wrong with JodaTime code.` (a) I don't see how the original poster was wrong with the Joda-Time code. (b) A quick reader might interpret that as you saying the Joda-Time code is incorrect when in fact it is correct. Perhaps you can finesse your answer.

Comment: HI,  This solution breaks for startDate =26-02-2016
and end date =03-03-2016
. Expected is 5, actual is 6. Please suggest a solution. Thanks

Comment: @Deepak I think you are wrong: *The total number of days between Friday, February 26th, 2016 and Thursday, March 3rd, 2016 is 6 days.* http://www.convertunits.com/dates/from/Feb+26,+2016/to/Mar+3,+2016

Comment: @MariuszS: Yes, actual number of days is 6 but as we are discussing to skip the leap years from subtraction of days we are expecting output to be 5 but the answers on this page will give us 6 and not 5(which is expected).

Comment: Expected answer is 5 because we want to ignore leap day.

Answer (score 3):

Just look at the year and the dayOfYear.

```
 int days = (end.year-start.year)*365 + end.dayOfYear - start.dayOfYear;
```

Answer (score 2):

Other answers don't work when the end date is a leap year and after the 29th Feb. 
You need to exclude the 29th Feb when working out the end date's day of the year.

Using Java 8's java.time package, you can pass in the isLeapYear boolean in when calculating the day-of-the-year of the first-of-the-month:

```
LocalDate.now().getMonth().firstDayOfYear(false)
```

This can then be combined into the rest of the calc:

```
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2011, 7, 1);
LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.of(2012, 4, 9);

int endDayOfYear = endDate.getMonth().firstDayOfYear(false) 
                         + endDate.getDayOfMonth() - 1;

int daysNoLeaps = ((endDate.getYear() - startDate.getYear()) * 365) 
                         + endDayOfYear - startDate.getDayOfYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1700762/andywilson) !! Your answer is correct but it doesn't work when the start date is in leap year and before the 29th February. The solve this issue, i added this ligne

> `int startDayOfYear = startDate.getMonth().firstDayOfYear(false) 
>                            + startDate.getDayOfMonth() - 1;`

```
  LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2011, 7, 1);
  LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.of(2012, 4, 9);

  int endDayOfYear = endDate.getMonth().firstDayOfYear(false) 
                     + endDate.getDayOfMonth() - 1;

  int startDayOfYear = startDate.getMonth().firstDayOfYear(false) 
                     + startDate.getDayOfMonth() - 1;`

  int daysNoLeaps = ((endDate.getYear() - startDate.getYear()) * 365) 
                     + endDayOfYear - startDayOfYear ;
```